# ContactSensor in Gazebo/Fuerte

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to get the Shadow-hand running in Fuerte, both the real one (EtherCAT)
and the simulated one. For grasp planning, information about contacts/collision
is obviously kind of important, and the Shadow hand simulation URDF model includes
Gazebo bumpers (contact sensors) on all fingers. The sensors were working fine
in Electric, and we got nice approximated wrenches from Gazebo.

In Fuerte, everything compiles, and the "deprecated" parser looks like it is doing the right thing of mapping the urdf sensor:contact tag to the  conversions as required by newest SDF.

Problem is, the first subscriber to one of the bumper topics triggers a
ContactSensor.GetContacts() call, which in turn detects that the "contacts"
data-structure is read but was NEVER initialized...

Please don't blaim this on the Shadow-Hand stack. We also tried using the Gazebo
contact-sensors on the PR2 gripper (vanilla Fuerte install on Ubuntu 12.04),
and the same error message from "ContactSensor.cc:237" results. Simply broken
in Fuerte, and possibly never tested before?

Cheers,
Norman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41765/contactsensor-in-gazebo/fuerte/) by [Norman Hendrich](https://answers.ros.org/users/3046/norman-hendrich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-08-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2012-08-19**:
Reported as an issue on Bitbucket.https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/13/contactsensor-in-gazebo-fuerte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just fixed it and added a patch to your issue ... I just don't know whether there would be a more appropriate way to push those changes to gazebo or whether John/Nate need to do so (I hope they see it given that there was no response to your ticket for almost 3 weeks). I'll also open one at code.ros.org where John did reply to my other gazebo ticket.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) with karma: 360 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) on 2012-09-08**:
it's fixed in the latest simulator_gazebo trunk now.